# RPC throwing "method not found" error when I'm trying to call from curl

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm new to Monero. When I'm using curl, all the wallet RPC calls are showing "method not found" error but `getnumberofblocks` method is working. I'm running the daemon, is it is necessary to run the wallet RPC? If yes, how do I run that?

Answer (score 1):

For wallet operations over RPC, you need to have the `monero-wallet-rpc` running. An example command to run the wallet RPC server:

```
monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file /some/wallet --rpc-bind-port 12345 \
    --prompt-for-password
```

(replacing the wallet file path and port number above to your choosing).

Other options can be specified also, seen via running `monero-wallet-rpc --help`.

All of the wallet RPC methods are documented [here](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html) and daemon RPC methods [here](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html).